# Ground shadows look inaccurate and muddy

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl, shadow

I have made a Threejs project, where I dynamically create a ground from perlin noise. Here is the code:

```
createGround() {

const resolutionX = 100
const resolutionY = 100
const actualResolutionX = resolutionX + 1 // plane adds one vertex
const actualResolutionY = resolutionY + 1


const geometryPlane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.sizeX, this.sizeY, resolutionX, resolutionY)

const noise = perlin.generatePerlinNoise(actualResolutionX, actualResolutionY)

let i = 0

for (let x = 0; x < actualResolutionX; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < actualResolutionY; y++) {
    let h = noise[i]
    }

    geometryPlane.vertices[i].z = h
    i++
  }
}

geometryPlane.verticesNeedUpdate = true
geometryPlane.computeFaceNormals()

const materialPlane = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  side: THREE.FrontSide,
  roughness: 1,
  metallness: 0,
})

const ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometryPlane, materialPlane)
geometryPlane.computeVertexNormals()
ground.name = GROUND_NAME
ground.receiveShadow = true
scene.add(ground)
```

}

I am happy with the geometry that is generated, but the problem is the shadows look really inaccurate.

[image]

Here is my code for the light:

```
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(
  'white',
  1,

)
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512 * 12 // default is 512. doesnt do anything
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512 * 12 // default is 512
light.castShadow = true
light.position.set(100, 100, 100)
scene.add(light)

light.shadowCameraVisible = true
```

My question is, how can I make the grounds shadow look more accuarate and defined, and show off the grounds geometry?

Rest of the code can be found here: https://github.com/Waltari10/workwork

Answer (score 0):

This shadow doesn't look so bad given the fact that you didn't setup any lights :).

I suppose this render works with some default lighting or lighting that you've added before thinking about shadows.

Try to add some directional light, simulating Sun direction and color and see if it helps, or tell us more about your lighting setup.

If you have any lights that render shadowmap already then check its resolution, you may need to make it bigger.

Comment: I added the code that I use for the light. How do I make the shadowmap bigger?

Comment: @Waltari About the shadowmap, have look at the documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow

Comment: I added light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512 * 12, but this doesn't seem to change anything whether I set it to 5 or 5000.

Comment: Also added the public git repo to question for all code.